# Looking for one word to describe a feeling

Tags: single-word-requests

A word for 'A simpler time', or 'sadly fond of or amused by', (but not melancholy) I'm trying to describe the naivety of seeing the internet referred to in a newspaper article from the mid 90's as the 'world wide web' and how silly that sounds now, and how different perhaps in a positive way it was a then.

Comment: And now I'm fondly, yet sadly remembering the angry protestations back then that the "World Wide Web" was a proper subset of "the Internet"...

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend **nostalgic**, which [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nostalgic) defines as:

> longing for or thinking fondly of a past time or condition

Comment: I agree, that would be the obvious choice, but it doesn't quite cover the emotion I'm after. Humorous naivety in some way, maybe childlike would work...

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like nostalgic (which actually sounds like a good fit to me), how about **pensive**?

Merriam-Webster defines it as:

> "musingly or dreamily thoughtful" and "suggestive of sad thoughtfulness."

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'yearning for the past'.

The yearning meaning is:
-A feeling of intense longing for something.

See these videos about it:
https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=yearning+for+the+past

Answer (score 0):

Would "**optimistic anticipation**" or "**naïve optimism**" be ideas that capture the sense in the right direction? Looking back, these short phrases seem "young" simplistic but true, yet also somehow "sad". I would suggest "**quaint**" to capture it in a single word.

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/quaint